# Can we read the variable name as a parameter value through the Bash command line execution?

Tags: linux, shell-script, arguments

We have a simple script where we execute the script using the command:

```
script.sh 123 456
```

#### Script content

```
FirstNum=$1
SecondNum=$2
```

Instead of using $1 and $2 inside the script, can we pass the command line while executing as below?

```
    script.sh FirstNum=123 SecondNum=456 (so that i dont want to call $1 , $2 inside the script)
```

Is there a way without using $1 & $2 and directly pass the values through the command line?

Comment: Can you share the reason you want to do this?

Comment: @Quasímodo.. We are trying to use a generic script and for each the value of the parameters and number of parameters are different. In order to use $1 , $2 i am trying to search if there is any way without defining

Comment: You could do `FirstNum=123 SecondNum=456 script.sh` instead - which would make the `FirstNum` and `SecondNum` available in the script's *environment*

Comment: Ravi, I don't quite understand. But for optional arguments, Rodrigo's answer below is the proper way.

Comment: What's the use-case here? The end-goal? Do you need the user to be able to pass options with arbitrary names, or do you just want to avoid them having to remember which order they have to the arguments when calling the script? (i.e. is it `script.sh <target> <command>` or `script.sh <command> <target>` ...)

Comment: @ikkachu.. I am trying for a possibility if i can pass variables values through the command line like (just want to avoid them having to remember which order they have to the arguments when calling the script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `bash` shell, you will want to use `getopts` to parse command line parameters.

From https://sookocheff.com/post/bash/parsing-bash-script-arguments-with-shopts/

> A common task in shell scripting is to parse command-line arguments to your script. Bash provides the getopts built-in function to do just that. This tutorial explains how to use the getopts built-in function to parse arguments and options to a bash script.

Example:

```
while getopts ":f:l:" opt; do
  case ${opt} in
    f )
      firstnum=$OPTARG
    l )
      lastnum=$OPTARG
      ;;
    \? )
      echo "Invalid option: $OPTARG" 1>&2
      ;;
    : )
      echo "Invalid option: $OPTARG requires an argument" 1>&2
      ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND -1))
```

I suggest using simple char parameters:

`script.sh -f 123 -l 456`

where `-f` is first, and `-l` is last.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo.. Along with first and last , do we have second , third anything like that ?

Comment: Do you mean like `--first` and `--last`?  If so, yes, see the man page for long options. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopt.1.html